# Starting and stopping a Tomcat server using Java

Tags: java, tomcat

I am developing a Java application in windows that employs the use of a Tomcat server. I have added the Tomcat server into Eclipse and have been able to start/stop it by clicking it. I now want to be able to start/stop the server by code but have not been able to find a working solution. Please help!

Comment: It is possible to have an embedded tomcat server in your java code.

Comment: I know it is possible but do you know how to implement it?